# Is it possible to bind a method of an external dll in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a datagrid to a datatable returned by a method in an external dll, in xaml. If i do the same in code-behind it works, so the logic is ok. Here is the relevant code:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:cdal="clr-namespace:genericDAL;assembly=generiDAL"
```

...

```
<Window.Resources>
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dbData" MethodName="cdal:getData" ObjectType="{x:Type cdal:genericDAL}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <sys:String>SELECT * FROM tabname;</sys:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

...

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource dbData}, Path=MethodParameters[0], BindsDirectlyToSource=True, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

Comment: is `cdal:genericDAL` tha class name that contains `cdal:getData` ?

Comment: yep. Fullname is generiDAL.genericDAL.

Comment: ok, let it put simple. is it possible to instantiate a custom class library belonging to an external project (yet referenced into the current one) in XAML as we reference the namespace System, declaring it's namespace and assembly like in the first line of code posted above? yes or no will do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: MethodName only require the method name without the cdal: thing. The method parameters string can have whitespaces in it. why i don't see any data into the datagrid?

Comment: bah, somewhat solved using a property exposing the data in the external assembly, and then binding to it. Still can't get why binding directly to the getData method doesn't produces results on VS xaml designer window.